# To validate a response item is an instance of a collection variable where the variable is an array in postman

Tags: postman

How can I validate a response item is an instance of a collection variable where the collection variable is an array in postman?

Here first I'm making an array from a response from a GET request.

```js
let arr = [];

for (item of response.books) {
    arr.push(item.isbn);
}
pm.collectionVariables.set("Books_ISBN", arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Now I want to evaluate a response data of a POST request with the "Books_ISBN" collection variable.
My POST request response is this

```json
{
    "books": [
        {
            "isbn": "9781449325862"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to do that like this but it is showing me error.

```js
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.test(pm.expect(response.books[0].isbn).to.be.an.instanceof(Books_ISBN));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman uses the [Chaijs](https://www.chaijs.com) assertion library internally. `to.be.an.instanceof` checks if the type is an `Array`. You want to use the `oneOf` method([Docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof)) like this:

```js
const Books_ISBN = pm.variables.get("Books_ISBN");

pm.test("my test", () => {
  pm.expect(response.books[0].isbn).to.be.oneOf(Books_ISBN);
});
```

You also maybe want to look at the postman documentation for [writing tests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/) and the documentation on [how to use variables in scripts](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#using-variables-in-scripts).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done that too. Still it shows an error of- ReferenceError: Books_ISBN is not defined. But I have defined Books_ISBN in previous request as a collection variable and I have added a SS in my post also where we can clearly see that Books_ISBN is defined.

Comment: I had the impression, that you already loaded the variable from postman. You did not show your error, so it was unclear what the real problem was. I edited the answer to include loading the variable from postman.

Comment: I have added an image of my error also in my main post but don't know why after posting only one image is shown. By the way it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your valuable response and time.

Comment: Nice to hear! Consider accepting one of the answers to mark this question as done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save array, object to as a varible, you should stringify first

```js
pm.collectionVariables.set("Books_ISBN", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

2. Variable is not existed in script, you have to `get` it first, don't forget to parse.

```js
let Books_ISBN = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get("Books_ISBN"));

pm.test("my test", () => {
  pm.expect(response.books[0].isbn).to.be.oneOf(Books_ISBN);
});
```